# handle invisible elements/popups with selenium in python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

**is there a way to interact with invisible popups/elements in selenium using python ?**

by **invisible or hidden** , i do not mean the elements with attribute hidden , neither do i mean that these elements are invisible from the user.

these invisible elements are those that do not appear in the inspect element section

**for example:** on a webapp screen where right click opens up a small options window which which has different options related to that webapp and its not the traditional browser right click options popup

by default this options popup does not appear in the inspect element , and it only appears when user right clicks on a certain section of the screen, the contents of this options popup differs depending on which setion of the screen the right click was performed on, and it disappears as soon as another click happens anywhere , even if i click on the inspect element section the options popup will disappear.

**is there any way to deal with this sort of popup?**

**Edit 1:** when i right click on the screen while the inspect element option is selected something related to the right click popup appears in the inspect element window , but as soon as i click on it to see the element ids , it disappears from the inspect element window

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve ,   https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

To search xpath of such dynamic elements use DOM break points:

[image]

And select break on subtree modification. Now all changes will break and pause the webpage rendering

[image]

Click resume execution or press f8 till your pop gets displayed